# Compare the index to a commit

Tags: git

I'm looking at a repository with a bunch of files "staged for commit" (i.e. added to the index but not committed yet.)  I suspect that the state of the index matches another branch.  Before I do a 'reset --hard' or some such, how can I make sure that's the case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to run a diff on the staged data with the `--cached` option. To include a branch, just enter the name of the branch.

```
git diff --cached feature/awesomeness
```

See [man git-diff](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-diff) for more info.